# Javascript logical search?

Tags: javascript, full-text-search, logic, boolean

I've built a search function for an array of javascript objects along the lines of:

1. User types text into a form input box
2. Loop through object array
3. If object text contains inputted text, push the object into a separate 'filtered' array
4. Display filtered array

This works fine using the string search() function built into javascript ie.

```
if(objectarray[i].text.search(userstring)>=0){  
    filteredarray.push(currentobject)  
};
```

Now the client would like to do a more advance search along the lines of:

find objects where text contains (x1 or x2) and (x3 or x4 or x5)

Where each of the x's is a word and an object would be pushed into the filtered collection when the above condition is met.

Is there a built in function which can handle this kind of complex boolean statement?

Comment: Consider this library which claims to use reparse to do something like what you describe: https://github.com/bloomtime/boolean-expression-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399396/replace-any-words-with-modified-version-of-themselves)

I take this:

```
var usersearchstring = "(x1 or x2) and (x3 or x4 or x5)";
```

And convert it using this:

```
usersearchstring = usersearchstring.replace(/[-\w]+/g, "targetstring.toLowerCase().search('$&')>=0");
```

Into this:

```
(targetstring.toLowerCase().search('x1')>=0 or targetstring.toLowerCase().search('x2')>=0) and (targetstring.toLowerCase().search('x3')>=0 or targetstring.toLowerCase().search('x4')>=0 or targetstring.toLowerCase().search('x5')>=0)
```

N.B. '>=0' is required to convert the numerical response returned by the search function into a boolean value

Comment: I like self-solving questions... :)