# Replace any words with modified version of themselves

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for an easy way to turn this string:

```
(java || javascript) && vbscript
```

Into this string:

```
(str.search('java') || str.search('javascript')) && str.search('vbscript')
```

ie replace each word in the string with `str.search('" + word + "')`

I've looked at `mystring.match(/[-\w]+/g);` which will pull any words out into an array (but not their position)

Comment: Can you give an example of what it looks like before and after? I am not understanding your description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `replace`:

```
mystring.replace(/[-\w]+/g, "str.search('$&')");
```

Note that this is an XSS hole, since the user input can contain `'`s.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I try that it outputs (str.search('$0') || str.search('$0')) && str.search('$0') Am I being daft?

Answer (score 0):

Just a fixed version with correct capture and using 1 as backtrack index. See details in "Specifying a string as a parameter" section of [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
mystring.replace(/([-\w]+)/g, "str.search('$1')");
```