# Treat phrase in quotes as a word in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a way to spilt a string into single words OR phrases where the phrase is enclosed in quotes. For example:

javascript 'sql server' vbscript

would be split into:

- javascript
- sql server
- vbscript

I got help yesterday with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399396/replace-any-words-with-modified-version-of-themselves) which splits the string into single words using

```
/[-\w]+/g
```

I've been wrestling with the dark art of regular expressions and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202435/php-explode-the-string-but-treat-words-in-quotes-as-a-single-word) which does a similar thing in php but even with the explanation it still doesn't make a great deal of sense to me (and doesn't work when I copy/paste into javascript!)

```
/"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|\S+/
```

Any help appreciated even a pointer to an easy to understand guide to regular expressions!

Comment: This is equivalent to parsing CSV where the separator is a space. It would be better to use a state machine.

Comment: Wow you guys are quick. Just found <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817646/javascript-split-string-on-space-or-on-quotes-to-array">this question</a> which uses:

    /\w+|"[^"]+"/g

Still in the dark as to how it works but it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the following:

```
/([-\w]+)|'([^']*)'/g
```

However, this is will fail if you have any form of single-quotes inside your quoted strings, that means, you cannot escape quotes with this construct.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var pattern = /('[^']+'|[-\w]+)/g;
var text = "javascript 'sql server' vbscript";
console.log(text.match(pattern));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this 
    `var text = ...
    var split = function(tx) {return tx.split("\'", }`
This should split it along quotes. Then just use the length to figure it out, as all the even numbered indexes are quotes. Then join the odd indexes and do a `split(" ")` to get the words